# DateTimeField migration error in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, datetime, migration, django-1.8

Previously my models' DateTimeField was initiated like

```
order_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today)
```

which was throwing

```
TypeError: Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found
```

when i tried to instantiate a blank object.
I fixed it with datetime.datetime.now().
But now when i try to migrate it shows the same error

```
TypeError: Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found
```

when i make a clean a migration in a fresh db its not having any problem.
I dont want to go on the route of making a fresh db since i don't have the permissions to do that in production. Is there any way to fix this?

Traceback:

```
  Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying xyz.0016_auto_20170728_0758...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/sayok/projects/invenv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/sayok/projects/invenv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/sayok/projects/invenv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/sayok/projects/invenv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/sayok/projects/invenv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/sayok/projects/invenv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/sayok/projects/invenv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/sayok/projects/invenv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/sayok/projects/invenv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 201, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/Users/sayok/projects/invenv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 484, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/Users/sayok/projects/invenv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 567, in _alter_field
    old_default = self.effective_default(old_field)
  File "/Users/sayok/projects/invenv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 194, in effective_default
    default = field.get_default()
  File "/Users/sayok/projects/invenv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 794, in get_default
    return self.default()
TypeError: Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found
```

migration file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
import datetime


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('p1', '0015_vgvjvvhvvj'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='analyze',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 909746)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='apiplaceorder',
            name='order_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 972820)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='hjjghjg',
            name='order_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 980004)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='banner',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 932895)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='clusterarticle',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 975352)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='clusterlog',
            name='updated_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 885144)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='customize',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 906463)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='faqtopic',
            name='created_date',

        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='greetingstouser',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 963740)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='kycsendemailtouser',
            name='send_date',
            field=models.DateField(default=datetime.date(2017, 7, 28)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='liveorder',
            name='order_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 971116)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='hgjgjgjgjg',
            name='last_login',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 976968)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='newsletter',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 940914)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='newslettertouser',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 942440)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='newsroom',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 944774)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='optimize',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 910911)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='order',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 910911)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='order',
            name='order_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 913976)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='orderaccountgraph',
            name='order_date',
            field=models.DateField(default=datetime.date(2017, 7, 28)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='orderbuy',
            name='order_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 918101)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='orderhold',
            name='hold_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 924012)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='ordersell',
            name='sell_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 921352)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='ordertrack',
            name='order_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 931269)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='partner',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 904619)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='recentlyviewedcluster',
            name='viewed_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 911741)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='seasongreetings',

        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='seasongreetings',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 962918)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='sitesetting',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 907550)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='subscribe',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 940109)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='team',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 905406)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='testimonial',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 903870)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='created_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 891457)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='usernotification',
            name='notification_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 912805)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='vghgh',
            name='application_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21, 957282)),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: delete migrations from migration folder and then try to migrate

Comment: Added @Alasdair

Comment: What does the failing migration `0016_auto_20170728_0758` look like? The traceback suggests it has `default=datetime` or `default=date` instead of `default=datetime.today`.

Comment: @stone I don't want to that because I had already done that and it worked but i have some production constraints, I can just rollback the last migration only.

Comment: @Alasdair added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in the traceback suggests that you have an incorrect default in a previous migration.

```
old_default = self.effective_default(old_field)
```

Check your old migrations in the app, and look for `default=datetime.datetime` or `default=datetime.date`. These should be `default=datetime.datetime.today` or `datetime.date.today` instead.

As an aside, you shouldn't use `default=datetime.now()`. Django is calling the function when you create the migration, and freezing it at `datetime(2017, 7, 28, 7, 58, 21)`. When you run the migration it will use that datetime, even if you run it many days from now. Use the callable `datetime.now` instead.

Comment: the initial migrate had
import datetime
default=datetime.date for both date and datetimefield.

Comment: In that case you need to fix the initial migration as I suggested.

Comment: If any other migrations have `default=datetime.datetime` or `default=datetime.date` you would have to fix them too. Ideally you should fix all of them, but the key thing to stop the error is to fix the latest migration that has the incorret default.

Comment: I deviated a bit I will elaborate down.

Answer (score 0):

I was enlightened by @Alasdair's suggestion.

What I did to resolve it:-

=>Update all default to datetime.datetime.now and datetime.date.today

=>replaced my 0001_initial(whichever is relevant for you) defaults with the datetime.datetime.now and datetime.date.today

=> Done, no migration suggestions or errors.